# Tkinter treeview does not display dataframe index row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tkinter

Through this function I am trying to display a dataframe using Tkinter treeview:

```
def zip_mean_median():
        global clean_df
        global zip1
        global clean_df_rows
        global columns
        clean_df['ACTIVITY DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(clean_df['ACTIVITY DATE']).dt.normalize()
        clean_df = clean_df.sort_values(by=['ACTIVITY DATE'])
        clean_df = clean_df.groupby([clean_df['ACTIVITY DATE'].dt.year, 'FACILITY ZIP'])['SCORE'].agg(['mean', 'median'])

        zip1 = ttk.Treeview(self.window, show='headings')
        columns = list(clean_df.columns)

        zip1["columns"] = columns
        zip1.grid()

        for i in columns:
            zip1.column(i, anchor=tk.W)
            zip1.heading(i, text=i, anchor=tk.W)

        for i, row in clean_df.iterrows():
            zip1.insert("", "end", values=list(row))

        zip1.place(relheight=1, relwidth=1)
        treescroll = tk.Scrollbar(self.window)
        treescroll.configure(command=zip1.yview)
        zip1.configure(yscrollcommand=treescroll.set)
        treescroll.grid()
```

The displayed dataframe should look like this:

```
ACTIVITY DATE FACILITY ZIP   MEAN         MEDIAN                   
2016          90001          91.166667    92.0
              90001-1127     96.200000    97.0
              90001-1646     94.000000    94.0
              90001-1771    100.000000   100.0
              90001-2714     91.000000    91.0
...                                ...     ...
2019          93552-2903     93.000000    93.0
              93552-4483     97.000000    97.0
              93553          99.000000    99.0
              93591          96.833333    96.5
              93591-3342     99.000000    99.0
```

However, using Tkinter and that function it looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

What am I missing in the function?

Comment: Looks like it's working? What's the issue? You may be interested in the pandastable project: https://github.com/dmnfarrell/pandastable

Comment: It doesn't show the "ACTIVITY DATE" and "FACILITY ZIP" columns. Those are quite important.

Comment: have you verified that your `columns` variable contains all the column headers and that the expected data is seen in the `row` of `clean_df.iterrows()`?

Comment: No, that's a great point! How can I do that?